# Grails 4: Many to many relationship, show data from joinTable

Tags: java, grails, groovy, h2

I have a question with many-to-many relationships in grails 4... When I try to get the data from the command_users table, it appears that it has nothing. I understand that, when you use the many-to-many, in the "pivot" table the relationships appear by their "id"... So what am I doing wrong?

The `user.groovy` Domain

```
import javax.persistence.Id

class User {
    @Id
    String mail; //PK
    String role;
    Boolean status;

    static constraints = {
        mail unique: true
        role blank: false
        status blank: false
    }

    static mapping =  {
        commands joinTable: [name: "command_users", key: "user_id"];
    }

    static hasMany = [commands: Command];

    public User(String mail, String role, Boolean status) {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.role = role;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

The `Command.groovy` Domain

```
import javax.persistence.Id

class Command {
  @Id
  String command; //PK
  String classResolve;

  static constraints = {
    command unique: true
    classResolve blank: false
  }

  static mapping = {
    users joinTable:[name: "command_users", key: "command_id"];
  }

  static hasMany = [users: User];

  public Command(String command, String classResolve) {
    this.command = command;
    this.classResolve = classResolve;
  }
}
```

A simple method into `TestController.groovy`

```
  @grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
  def initUserData() {
    User luis = new User("luis@mail.com", "admin", true);
    User edgar = new User("edgar@mail.com", "admin", true);
    User julio = new User("julio@mail.com", "admin", true);

    Command helloCommand = new Command("hello", "Hello");
    Command worldCommand = new Command("world", "World");
    helloCommand.addToUsers(luis).addToUsers(edgar).addToUsers(julio).save();
    worldCommand.addToUsers(luis).addToUsers(edgar).addToUsers(julio).save();
    
    luis.save();
    edgar.save();
    julio.save();
  }
```

When I search in the DB (use h2 for test) i have the next result:

My table structure:

[image: The tables]

Result from table users:

[image: User Table]

Result from command table:

[image: Command Table]

But noting in joinTable CommandUser

[image: join table]

¿What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show commanduser domain class?

Comment: I don't have a CommandUser domain.

Comment: try saving your users before you call `Command.addToUsers()`